# Expected ']' and Extraneous ']' before ':'

Tags: ios, objective-c, constants, nsnotificationcenter

I am trying to write this code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:EVENT_TIME_OVER object:nil];
                                            ^          ^
```

`EVENT_TIME_OVER` is defined in a `Constants.h` file like so:

```
#define EVENT_TIME_OVER @"event.TIME_OVER";
```

Why would I get the errors: `Expected ']'` and `Extraneous ']' before ';'` where the `^` mark above? I have used similar code before in other apps, but this time it will not compile because of these errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace this

```
#define EVENT_TIME_OVER @"event.TIME_OVER";
```

with

```
#define EVENT_TIME_OVER @"event.TIME_OVER"
```

Comment: Wha!? why would that matter? That fixed it!

Comment: It matters because `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"event.TIME_OVER"; object:nil]` isn't legal syntax.

Comment: I just didn't know that the semicolon would be apart of the definition, I assumed it would be an end-of-line like anywhere else. Thanks

Comment: @brenjt Welcome to C! :)